# Multiline text in wxpython

Tags: python-3.x, wxpython

I want to put a big text in a panel using wxpython and use, to display it, more than one line,but i can't find out how to change line.

Thank you

Here is an example:

```
import wx
class My_Frame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
            super(My_Frame,self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
            self.SetSize((600,600))
            self.SetTitle('Example')
            self.Centre()
            self.Show(True)



            self.panel = wx.Panel(self)
            self.text = wx.StaticText(self.panel,label='big text')



def main():       
    app = wx.App()
    My_Frame(None)
    app.MainLoop()





main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a [wx.TextCtrl](https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/wx.TextCtrl.html?highlight=textctrl) with the following [style](https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/wx.TextCtrl.html?highlight=textctrl#styles-window-styles).

- wx.TE_MULTILINE: The text control allows multiple lines. If this style is not specified, line break characters should not be used in the controls value.